# spTransform error

Tags: raster, r

I am using R to analyze some raster files using the packages "raster", "rgdal" and "tigris" in my workspace. I'm trying to use the function spTransform on a dataset using the following code:

```
transStates <- spTransform(threeStates, CRS(fire@crs@projargs))
```

However when I run this code I get the following error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘spTransform’ for signature ‘"sf", "CRS"’
```

A similar question was asked in another thread and they suggested using st_transform if it is a data.file class but R doesn't recognise that function. What could be the problem in this case?

Comment: If the other “thread” was on this site, can you provide a link to that Q&A, please?

Answer (score 1):

> A similar question was asked in another thread and they suggested
> using st_transform if it is a data.file class but R doesn't recognise
> that function. What could be the problem in this case?

There are two different, incompatible spatial data types in R with two different, packages with differently-named functions to work with them.

The older types use the `sp` and `rgdal` packages, and create data called things like "SpatialPolygonsDataFrames". You use `spTransform` to transform those.

The newer types use the `sf` package, and use functions beginning `st_` to work on them, such as `st_transform` to change coordinate systems.

You have tried to use an `sp` function on an `sf` data object, hence the error:

```
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘spTransform’ for signature ‘"sf", "CRS"’
```

Without knowing exactly how you got an `sf` object (`threeStates`) or what you intend to do with it its hard to give an exact way for you to proceed here. But to convert from `sp` to `sf` you can so `st_as_sf(something)`, and to convert the other way from `sf` to `sp` you can do `as(thing, "Spatial")`.

So...

install the `sf` package with `install.packages("sf")` and then after doing `library(sf)` then:

```
spTransform(as(threeStates,"Spatial"), CRS(fire@crs@projargs))`
```

might get you past this (although we have no idea what `fire` is...)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and it was the same as one of the ones you suggested. I used the code "as(raster_file, 'Spatial') instead of "as_Spatial" and it worked. Must have been an issue with the file type, but the code has been copied directly from the markdown of an online tutorial so I don't know why it didn't work initially.

Thanks for the help!